# Collection data in Spring Java based configuration

Tags: spring, spring-java-config

I am working on migrating Spring XML configuration to Java based configuration. During the process, I run into a situation of collection type data and don't know how to handle it in the Java based configuration. For example,

```
<util:map id="imageDimensions" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
    <entry key="regular" value="640x480" />
    <entry key="small" value="320x240" />
    <entry key="thumb" value="200x150" />
</util:map>
```

If I don't want to have this map data in Java configuration, what I need to do about it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add bean in your configuration:

```
@Bean
public Map<String, String> imageDimensions() {
  // create your map
}
```

If you prefer to have your map data in for example properties file you have to inject Environment field and then by invoking getProperty() retrieve and set all needed elements.

```
 @Configuration
 public class AppConfig {

     @Inject Environment env;

     @Bean
     public Map<String, String> imageDimensions() {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        // create your map
        return map;
     }

 }
```

You can also of course read this data from xml or yaml file

Comment: Thanks for your input. I find the import resource approach with @ImportResource is more suitable for my need. That allows me change the configuration data without compiling Java code.

Comment: With ImportResource you will still have part of your configuration in XML.  My solution allowed you to read it (manually) for example from yaml or properties file